# How to stop video after X button is clicked

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Currently, the video does not `player.stopVideo();` in the code.

**To reproduce:** Click 1 svg play button, then click the **X** and you will see that.

How is that fixed in the code so that the same video stops after clicking the **X**?

**Updated Codes:**

Click **Run**, not update to test JSitor code:

Also, autoplay works inside JSitor: https://jsitor.com/qYKcpdB0tj

Backup copy: https://jsfiddle.net/0q63tr2m/

```
const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const players = [];

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
  }

  function addPlayer(video, settings) {
    const defaults = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      videoId: video.dataset.id,
      width: 640
    };
    defaults.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };
```

You can see the video still playing here:

[image]

Comment: Add this stopPlaying function and call it in exitHandler: 
`function stopPlaying() {
    var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(iframes, iframe => { 
      iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ event: 'command', 
    func: 'stopVideo' }), '*');
   });
  }`
Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/nhovfpa6/1/

Comment: After clicking on the same svg play button again, the video does not play on its own.

How is that fixed? See Here: https://jsitor.com/5wzu-E-W9w

Comment: I've tried a lot of ways mate but it doesn't seem to work as you need it. That's all I could do :/ 
Can I put my comment over as an answer so that you could accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is as follow:

1. Add an id to your iframe element like so: `id="iframe"`
2. Remove `player.stopVideo();` from `createStopHandler` function
3. On your `createStopHandler` function, add following code(if you want your video to stop and not pause, then change the func snippet `"func":"pauseVideo"` into `"func":"stopVideo"`):

```js
var frame = document.getElementById("iframe");
frame.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
```

This should do it. Here you can see it working: https://jsfiddle.net/vjbex6t1/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
 function addClickToHome(goHome) {
    goHome.forEach(function addEventHandler(goHome) {
        goHome.addEventListener("click", homeClickHandler);
       //STOP PLAYER AFTER HOME IS CLICKED 
    });
}
```

Initialize some variable with player globally and stop it when button is pressed to home

Comment: sure give me 2 min

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out,

```
var videoURL = $('#playerID').prop('src');
videoURL = videoURL.replace("&autoplay=1", "");
$('#playerID').prop('src','');
$('#playerID').prop('src',videoURL);
```